# Set an optional parameter in jpa query with "in" condition

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

I am using JPA to execute a native query as given below

```
@Query(value="SELECT pintable.pin from pintable s 
              where s.status=1 
              and (:pincodes is null or ifnull(s.pincode,'') in (:pincodes)) "
              , nativeQuery = true)
```

It is working fine for optional pincode (null) also working fine with a single pincode search.
When I use multiple values for search, getting an error as given below.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT pintable.pin from pintable s where s.status=1 and ((?,?) is null or ifnull(s.pincode,'') in (?,?))    
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Please let me know how to handle with multiple value optional search.

Comment: I didn't understand this condition `(?,?) is null`. Can you remove that condition and see whether it is working?

Answer (score 1):

To handle multiple values for an optional parameter in JPA, especially when using the IN clause, you might need to adjust your approach. One way to address this is to handle the optional parameter differently based on whether it's null or contains multiple values.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT pintable.pin FROM pintable s WHERE s.status = 1 " +
        "AND (:pincodes IS NULL OR ifnull(s.pincode, '') IN :pincodes)", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findByPincodes(@Param("pincodes") List<String> pincodes);
```

In your calling code:

If you want to find by a single pincode, pass a list containing only that pincode.
If you want to find by multiple pincodes, pass a list containing all those pincodes.

For example:

```
List<String> singlePincode = Collections.singletonList("12345");
List<String> multiplePincodes = Arrays.asList("12345", "56789");

// For single pincode
List<String> resultSingle = repository.findByPincodes(singlePincode);

// For multiple pincodes
List<String> resultMultiple = repository.findByPincodes(multiplePincodes);
```

This way, the query will handle both scenarios: when pincodes is null (ignoring the pincode condition) and when it contains multiple values, working with the IN clause appropriately. Adjust the code as needed based on your specific use case and data structures.